# Lookup on Custom FIELD on standard Asset Object

Tags: custom-field, lookup, search

I've migrated asset entries off a legacy Org, both orgs use auto numbers, and in the new org I've saved the old auto number (that is API field Name) in a `Legacy_Name__c` field. Colleagues need to lookup assets and sometimes they'll have to use the legacy names eg `A-00015` but `A-00015` is some completely different item in the new Org.

How can the lookup search use, if at all possible the `Legacy_Name__c` field as well as Name? Yes, they'll see 2 results but because the lookup results table shows additional info they'll know which asset to chose.

How can I add `Legacy_Name__c` in the lookup results view as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to display Assets after a search on Salesforce with several fields as the results of your search you can easily do this by going to the Asset object and changing the Search Results.

Click on **Setup**-->**Customize** (under Build)-->**Asset**

After you clicked on Asset you will have a number of options bellow this object. Click on **Search Layouts**. Now click on **Edit** left of **Search Results**. Move to the **Selected Fields** box all the fields you want to use for your search results. Here you can use the Auto-Number and any reference from the old system. - Click **Save**.

Now if you search for an Asset you will receive the information you need to know, from the old system and with the new Auto-Number in SFDC. This should indicate users which Asset they are dealing with.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm giving that a go, cheers. Also tried mass updating the names to the legacy names in my sandbox but dataloader just ignored every row, is the Name restricted for that kind of update? I can edit the name in sfdc web interface just fine on per-item basis..

Comment: You should be able to run Data Loader and modify the Name field. Are you sure that you have the correct mapping? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: No errors, finishes instantly with 0 success and 0 error, it's been a long day.. Mapping should be fine only 3 columns. It is an auto number however..

Comment: Yeah I think it was a combination of me not changing the field to Text first and/or the auto number start position being larger than the the names I wanted to update

Comment: Are you now able to implement your changes?

Comment: Yes everything mended. The auto number came from the record type in a way hence me not spotting the peculiarities in time